# wicked pdf using application layout, not intended pdf layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

gem includes and installs

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.6.6'
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 2.7'
gem 'mobility', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.9'
```

An initializer defines (based on prior experience):

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/Users/main/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf'
```

`assets.rb` should precompile as follows

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( initialise.css foundation.css zapp.css )
```

A layout `pdf.html.erb` was created with a couple of options to test for font rendering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "initialise" %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "foundation" %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "zapp" %>
    <%# stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("initialise") %>
    <%# stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("foundation") %>
    <%# stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("zapp") %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller action defines respond_to blocks

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: 
          "#{@individual.name_last}_#{@individual.name_first}_t_up",
           layout: 'pdf', 
           encoding: 'utf8'
     end
    end
```

the link rendering  `<%= link_to fa_icon("file-pdf-o", class: 'fa-lg'), t_up_individual_path(@individual, format: :pdf), target: '_pdf' %>` renders
`href="/individuals/94/t_up.pdf?locale=en"`

However, the net result is styles are not applied.  Double-check by removing the `pdf.html.erb` layout from its folder and the error for lack of a layout is returned. SO the proper layout is being used.  it seems the absolute paths are amiss.
Also attempted, with the same results, an absolute path to an external server:
`wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "[fully_verifiable_url]"`

What is wrong/missing with the stylesheet definitions?

*incidentally, how can precompilation be asserted?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per official documentation you should name the file `pdf.pdf.erb`. Change the `html` extension to `pdf`.

```rb
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf:    'file_name',
               ...
               layout: 'pdf', # for a pdf.pdf.erb file
               ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Read more:
https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#advanced-usage-with-all-available-options